# Visual Studio 2013 and MSBuild command line switches

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Is there a way to specify msbuild switches like /p:option=value within Visual Studio 2013?

Comment: Visual Studio does not run `MSBuild.exe`, so it cannot pass switches in that way. You might be able to achieve the results you want by editing the MSBuild project file directly though.

Comment: This is a bit vague. Maybe if you specify which switches exactly (Compiler options? Other build options? Custom variable definitions?) there is an appropriate answer.

Comment: I have a property in my project file which I intend to overwrite with a value passed to by a switch /p:... or something similar. Changing the project file is not an option.

Comment: Is adding a hook to the project file would be possible? What I have in mind is to import a targets file in case it is exists. This target file would then redefine the property which its value is to be overridden.

Comment: @AmnonShochot yes that should be the way, maybe post it as an answer? Msbuild has a couple of these hooks alraedy but none (afaik) are project-specific. There's the ImportBefore/ImportAfter mechanism, and for C++ projects there's $(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props

Comment: @AmnonShochot This comes close to the result I want to achieve, although it adds a little overhead in dealing with files in the solution which are out of version control. But it is still the best opinion so far.

Comment: Cool. Added it as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formalizing my comment from above.

A possible solution may be to have a targets file (e.g. `VisualStudioOverrides.targets`) that defines the properties to be overridden and their values. Then, if this file exists then the csproj file will import it, thus override the relevant properties.
Such an import statement should be placed at the bottom of the csproj file (after the properties to be overridden were defined) and would look something like:

```
<Import Project="$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\VisualStudioOverrides.targets" Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\VisualStudioOverrides.targets')" />
```