# How to support complex project configurations in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, msbuild

I'm working on a project that requires a whole multi-dimensional matrix of configurations. Theres (Debug / Release / Optimised / Final), (Editor / Non-Editor), (Win32 / Win64 / iOS / Android), (USA / Europe / Asia) etc. All with different build targets (ie win32_europe_debug_editor.exe) and their own set of libraries, includes, #defines and so on.

Is there a way to add more dropdowns to the project configuration toolbar in Visual Studio? At the moment there's "Platforms" and "Configurations". I've got  win32/win64/ios/android in Platforms, but there's still dozens of different Configurations.

"Don't set your project up like this" is, unfortunately, out of my hands - this is the way the contracting company wants to do it, and we're bound to that.

I know that this is made a lot easier with just going through MSBuild, but I'm just hoping to find out if there's a way to do it while at least partially staying within the Visual Studio interface, just as that's what the rest of the team is used to. It's a tricky enough setup as it is, and I'd like to minimise the amount of extra cognitive load they have to take on!

Thanks!

Comment: There is no built-in way to do that: how could VS know about al your custom named properties? The only thing I can think of is writing an extension which adds dropdowns for arbitrary properties, and applies those properties to the build. Doesn't have to be complicated: for instance you could simply have your extension create a file with the needed properties/values and then use something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29409111/visual-studio-2013-and-msbuild-command-line-switches to apply them to the build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add more parameters into .sln file, it is fixed to support only two -- Platform and Configuration. If you want Visual Studio to work with different parameters of your product, you have two options.

1.Expand your Configuration parameter to contain additional values, like a cross product of multiple sets. E.g. for your case, where your original parameters as follows:

```
Configuration={Debug, Release, Optimised, Final}
Editor={Editor, NonEditor}
Region={USA, Europe}
```

you might convert them to equivalent selection of configurations:

```
Configuration={Debug_Editor_USA, Debug_Editor_Europe, Debug_NonEditor_USA, Debug_NonEditor_Europe, Release_Editor_USA, ... }
```

This of course has scalability problems, so it only works with small set of additional parameters. Also, note that similar attempt to expand selection of Platform parameter would likely not work, because many targets work only with standard values of Platform property.

2.You can leave additional parameters in your .**proj files, with defaults that you can override from environment variables. E.g. if you have the following section in every project in your solution:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EditorType Condition="'$(IDE_EDITOR_TYPE)' != ''">$(IDE_EDITOR_TYPE)</EditorType>
    <EditorType Condition="'$(EditorType)' != ''">NonEditor</EditorType>
    <RegionType Condition="'$(IDE_REGION_TYPE)' != ''">$(IDE_REGION_TYPE)</RegionType>
    <RegionType Condition="'$(RegionType)' != ''">USA</RegionType>
</PropertyGroup>
```

,then values of additional parameters could be overriden by setting env variables, while default values will be `NonEditor` and `USA`. To have your VS IDE pick up non-default values, you have to do the following:

- Open up VS cmd window
- cd to location of your .sln
- `set IDE_EDITOR_TYPE=Editor`
- `set IDE_REGION_TYPE=Europe`
- `devenv MySolution.sln`

VS IDE, launched this way will use these settings to perform build, debug, Intellisense, etc. BTW, when you change parameters, Intellisense needs to be rebuilt, the easiest way is to delete file `MySolution.sdf` before launching devenv.